# ANTD Calendar automatically switches selected date when a month changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use CALENDAR component from ANT Design and I need to make the date selectable ONLY when you click the specific DAY associated with a specific month. But there is a problem. Whenever I change a month (subtract or add) the selected date automatically changes.

For example:

1. 18.8. is selected and I have August panel table shown.
2. I switch the month on July (7.)
3. The selected date is now 18.7.

How do I prevent this, please?

There is no code needed since I have noticed this functionality is built inside the component. :/

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to remove `onSelect` property from the Calendar props and call `onSelect` through `onClick` on custom rendered tag.